# Is it possible to train gpt2 with our own data to generate text?

Tags: python, nlp, gpt-2

I want to use gpt2 to generate text. I tried to train the model on my own dataset but at the end it generate one word only. I couldn't find a solution to this issue. Is there a way to solve this?[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1816?

Comment: Yes, it's very useful thank you.